# Deploying azure function from IntelliJ removes all app settings

Tags: azure, azure-functions, intellij-plugin

I'm using Azure IntelliJ Toolkit, to deploy Azure function.
This is the screenshot showing how it is getting deployed:
[image]

App Settings here is non-optional, and whatever is inserted here will override anything that already exists in Portal, as shown below:
[image]

This seems like serious bug, but wonder if there is any workaround.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If there are any changes in the application settings from Local IDE, those will be reflected in the Azure portal after every deployment.

Comment: Thanks @HariKrishna for your reply! The use of word "reflect" is bit generous term. What's happening is that local deployment is NOT adding to what's already out there, but removing ALL, and then adding the settings defined at the time of deployment.

Comment: I can see in your IntelliJ IDE, only one app setting is defined, that is added in Azure portal. If you want to add more settings in application settings configuration, you should not remove the existing from the IntelliJ Toolkit IDE, you have to add the new setting with the existing ones and save.

Answer (score 0):

Created the basic Azure Java Function Http Trigger in IntelliJ IDE and published/deployed to Azure Cloud with the default application settings:

[image]

In the Azure Portal > Function App Configuration Menu > Application Settings:

[image]

If you remove any application settings from the local IDE IntelliJ and save, the same will be in the Azure Cloud:
[image]

[image]

If you want to add more application settings, do not remove the existing ones in the IntelliJ Azure Function App Properties Window because that is local Window of the Azure Portal Function App Configuration.

For running the function project locally with the additional configuration, you have to add them in the code file of `local.settings.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the screen-shot response! It's very interesting that your local IDE was able to populate default application settings (which includes AzureWebJobsStorage). Did you create Azure Function (just the resource, but without jar) from local IDE, or from Azure Portal?

Comment: Created Azure Functions From local IDE and also created in Azure Portal